# Device orientation metadata

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have designed a website using media-query. 
In the browser it is looking perfect. But when i am checking in the tablet or in mobile device, in portrait mode it is good,

but when I am changing the device orientation portrait to landscape then it is not looking perfect. So my doubt is "is there any meta-data to disable the device orientation, so even though user change the device orientation then the content will not rotate."

thanks,
naresh kumar.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you properly, you no need to disable the orientation but rather you can adjust screen elements even when the device is rotated. You can use the below queries:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }
@media all and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Because a good design should fit in all devices and in all orientations perfectly...

Comment: when you find the answer is right please vote it ... thanks again